# Is there a way to avoid going to chrome://downloads/ to find a download link?

Tags: google-chrome

When downloading something in Chrome, there would be a small icon showing download progress. I would like to copy its link, but right-clicking the icon doesn't show anything. I have to go to chrome://downloads/ to find the link.

Is there a way to avoid going to chrome://downloads/ while still finding the link? (Note that some websites will redirect the link you click, so I don't copy from the website directly.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by **Right clicking** **on the download link** & choosing **Copy link address**

[image: Copy link address]

However this won't work if the link is hidden behind script.

In that case your only choice is some **download manager extension** that shows you the URL in its menu.

[Like this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-master/mcceagdollnkjlogmdckgjakjapmkdjf?hl=en-US)

[image]